# How to create High Availability cluster with PostgresSQL on Windows Server 2016

Tags: high-availability, windows-server-2016, postgresql-12, pgpool

I am trying to create an HA environment with PostgresSQL server. I have two nodes with Windows Server 2016 installed on it. Due to client limitations we cannot use Linux servers and I am tasked with creating an HA environment for Postgres SQL.

Can someone please guide me as how to go about creating it.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/high-availability.html

Comment: I have read the documentation @CodeCaster but I am not getting any direction on how to do it on Windows Server. Please provide relevent documentation for Windows Server.